# FeignClient Configuration in non-web Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

I have a Spring Boot application which runs as a web application or a console application based on `spring.main.web-application-type` argument.

Application.java

```java
@EnableFeignClients
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And ConsoleApplication.java

```java
@Component
@ConditionalOnNotWebApplication
public class ConsoleApplication implements ApplicationRunner {
    private final SomeFeignClient someFeignClient;

    public ConsoleApplication(SomeFeignClient someFeignClient) {
        this.someFeignClient = someFeignClient;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) {
        someFeignClient.someMethod(); // This calls feign client method
    }
}
```

SomeFeignClient.java

```java
@FeignClient(name = "my-api", url = "http://example.com", configuration = MyFeignConfiguration.class)
public interface SomeFeignClient {

    @RequestLine("GET /some/api")
    String someMethod();
}
```

MyFeignConfiguration.java

```java
// No @Configuration annotation
public class MyFeignConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Contract feignContract() {
        return new feign.Contract.Default();
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultAccessTokenRequest accessTokenRequest() {
        return new DefaultAccessTokenRequest();
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultOAuth2ClientContext context(AccessTokenRequest accessTokenRequest) {
        return new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(accessTokenRequest);
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientCredentialsResourceDetails resourceDetails() {
        ClientCredentialsResourceDetails resourceDetails = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
        resourceDetails.setClientId("CLIENT_ID");
        resourceDetails.setClientSecret("CLIENT_SECRET");
        resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri("TOKEN_URL");
        resourceDetails.setGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS.getValue());
        return resourceDetails;
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestInterceptor feignRequestInterceptor(OAuth2ClientContext context, OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails details) {
        return new OAuth2FeignRequestInterceptor(context, details);
    }
}
```

The client works and picks up the configuration from `MyFeignConfiguration.java` when running as a web application (`spring.main.web-application-type=SERVLET`), but does not when it's running as a console application (`spring.main.web-application-type=NONE`) and uses the default configuration.

I tried searching in the [Spring Cloud OpenFeign documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/reference/html/) and [Spring Cloud documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html), but could not find anything specific around it.

Has anybody come across similar situation and know what might be causing it?

Thanks.

Comment: I created a minimal sample and it works fine for me. Can you provide a sample?

Comment: It seems to be working fine when the `MyFeignConfiguration` class is in the same package. However, I am loading it from a library, and it's not working.

Comment: @Garbage i m facing the same issue with spring boot console application. can you help how you fix this issue? when i run the application i m getting below error.  Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientService' in your configuration.